# Find all natural $n$ numbers.

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

Find all natural $n$ numbers such that
$15(n!)^2+1$ is divisible by $2n-3$.
My try: First I assumed $2n-3$ is not prime number. Let $a$ be divisor of $2n-3$. It's clear that $a<n-1$, so $15(n!)^2$ is divisible by $a$. Which means $15(n!)^2+1$ is not divisble by $a$. But it is given that $15(n!)^2+1$is divisble by $n$ which means it is divisible by $a$ too. But we have already proved it is not. Contradiction!
So $2n-3$ must be prime number. Now if we change $2n-3$ as $p$. We can say $((p+3)/2)!*((p+3)/2)!$ is congruent to $-1$ by $p$ module. By Wilson's theorem $((p+3)/2)!*((p+3)/2)!$ is congruent to $(p-1)!$ by $p$ module

Comment: That's an interesting question.  Show some work and/or tell us what you think so the question won't close.

Answer (score 1):

it has been checked by a computer up to n = 40000. the set now contains the numbers {1,2,10,77}. I do not have a proof that there are no new numbers that satisfy the conditions for the set above n = 40000. I can see why people thought this question was impossible. it may actually be a nice problem that is solvable if you can prove that the statement is false for n > 77. the rest are checked by computer.